# Type-hint a custom class enum

Tags: python

I have a enum class, which is class variable inside person class. I am getting typehint error for `types` class variable.

I tried as below to typehint  `types` class variable.

- XyzTypes
- "XyzTypes"
- Type[XyzTypes]
- TypeVar["T"]

None of them work. Getting error as `error: Incompatible types in assignment...`

```
class XyzTypes(StrEnum):

    MNO: str = "mno"
    PQR: str = "pqr"
    
    @classmethod
    def get_default(cls) -> str:
        return cls.MNO
```

```
class Person:

    types: XyzTypes = XyzTypes
```

Accessing as `Person.types.get_default()`

Please help.

**Edit: 1**
I am using python 3.11

**Edit: 2**

Further I modified the code and made that variable private as below

```
class Person:

    _types: type[XyzTypes] = XyzTypes  # Working now

    @classmethod
    def get_type_enum(cls) -> ???:
        return cls._types
```

I tried below

- type[XyzTypes]
- "XyzTypes"

Getting error as `error: Incompatible return value type`

Comment: You are trying to treat `XyzTypes` as an instance of itself. The only type that *is* an instance of itself is `type`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce that error using `type[XyzTypes]` or `Type[XyzTypes]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Person.types` to refer to the class `XyzTypes` (or a subclass thereof), the correct type hint is

```
class Person:
    types: type[XyzTypes] = XyzTypes
```

More generally, if `Person.types` just needs to be an enumerated type, use

```
from enum import EnumType


class Person:
    types: EnumType = XyzTypes
```

where all enumerated types are instances of the (meta)class `EnumType`.

Comment: Hi chepner, It is working now. Further I made that variable private and created a method, getting error on return type.